# Bootstrap: Align content to baseline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to align contents to the baseline. I am working with the bootstrap framework, and have been unable to do so.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-12">
          <span class="h5">My Games</span>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right" v-b-modal.create-game>New Game</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Which produces this:
[image]

When I consult the bootstrap documentation, [it says to do this:](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#align-items)

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-baseline">...</div>
```

But when I do this or apply the same classes to the col-12:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-12">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-baseline">
               <span class="h5">My Games</span>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right" v-b-modal.create-game>New Game</button>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

it results in this:
[image]

[I looked at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577430/bootstrap-vertical-align-a-row-in-a-col), which suggests flex and align-items:baseline to the row div. However when I did this, nothing happens.

Could anyone suggests to me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it? I would like the text to be placed to the baseline, and for them to still be spread apart from one another.

I would like it to look close to this:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: To anyone trying to figure this out. Please read below to Nidhin's answers and read the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `margin` for your `.h5` and use `.align-items-end`

```css
span.h5 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-end">
      <span class="h5 m-0">My Games</span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right" v-b-modal.create-game>New Game</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Nidhin, thank you for replying! While that does get it to the baseline, it still squishes the button and the text together. Is there a way around this?

Comment: `it still squishes the button` can you explain, please? like do you need a gap?

Comment: Sure Nidhin. I want the button to still float right like in the first picture, and to still be spaced out far from the text. I would just like the text to be aligned to the baseline, so that the text does not look higher than the button.

Comment: aah, i forgot about image 1, you can add `flex-grow:1` to your `span`. have edited mate, please check

Answer (score 0):

You can add some css & see result

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row" style="margin: 0px;">
     <div class="col-12" style="display: inline-block;width: 100%;background-color: #efefef;padding: 15px;">
          <span class="h5" style="margin: 10px 0 0 0;display: inline-block;">My Games</span>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right" v-b-modal.create-game>New Game</button>
     </div>
</div>
```